# How to merging two lists in React?

Tags: reactjs, arraylist, filter

I need help with merging 2 lists in ReactJs.
for example,
list one :

```
[
{id:1,name:"abc",city:"ddd"},
{id:2,name:"cde",city:"ddd"},
{id:3,name:"ttt",city:"fff"}
]
```

list two:

```
[
{id:1,name:"abc"},
{id:3,name:"ttt"}
]
```

and the result that I want to get is

```
[
{id:1,name:"abc",city:"ddd"},
{id:3,name:"ttt",city:"fff"}
]
```

What is the best clearly way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use filter and some array method.

```js
 const arr1 = [
  {id:1,name:"abc",city:"ddd"},
  {id:2,name:"cde",city:"ddd"},
  {id:3,name:"ttt",city:"fff"}
];

const arr2 = [
  {id:1,name:"abc"},
  {id:3,name:"ttt"}
];


const filteredArray = arr1.filter((el) => {
  return arr2.some((x) => {
    return x.id === el.id && x.name === el.name;
  });
});

console.log(filteredArray);
```

Comment: thanks! it's worked! but if i want to return array like ["abc","ttt"]? (only names) what's the best solution for that?

Comment: at the end add map method to get only name in array  - `const filteredArray = arr1.filter((el) => {
  return arr2.some((x) => {
    return x.id === el.id && x.name === el.name;
  });
}).map(item => item.name);`